# In Numbers 4:32 was each son of Merari responsible for a single part of the tabernacle?

Tags: mishkan-tabernacle, levites-leviyim, parshat-nasso

In the census of Numbers 4, the workmen available were 3,200:

> JPS Numbers 4:
>
> 42And those that were numbered of the families of the sons of Merari,
>   by their families, by their fathers’ houses, 43from thirty years old
>   and upward even unto fifty years old, every one that entered upon the
>   service, for service in the tent of meeting, 44even those that were
>   numbered of them by their families, were three thousand and two
>   hundred. 45These are they that were numbered of the families of the
>   sons of Merari, whom Moses and Aaron numbered according to the
>   commandment of the LORD by the hand of Moses.

Their job was to transport the pieces of the tabernacle. And in verse 32 it is said that they were to be assigned by name:

> 29As for the sons of Merari, thou shalt number them by their families,
>   by their fathers’ houses; 30from thirty years old and upward even unto
>   fifty years old shalt thou number them, every one that entereth upon
>   the service, to do the work of the tent of meeting. 31And this is the
>   charge of their burden, according to all their service in the tent of
>   meeting: the boards of the tabernacle, and the bars thereof, and the
>   pillars thereof, and the sockets thereof; 32and the pillars of the
>   court round about, and their sockets, and their pins, and their cords,
>   even all their appurtenance, and all that pertaineth to their service;
>   **and by name ye shall appoint the instruments of the charge of their burden.** 33This is the service of the families of the sons of Merari,
>   according to all their service, in the tent of meeting, under the hand
>   of Ithamar the son of Aaron the priest.’

Does this mean that a specific person was charged by name to safely transport a particular piece? It seems like there would be enough people available.